# Can't create columns no matter what

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm creating database with:

```
public static final String TABLE_MARKETS = "MARKET";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_PRICE = "price";
public static final String COLUMN_SUBSCRIBED = "sub";
public static final String COLUMN_MARKET_ID = "marketid";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";

private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
        + TABLE_MARKETS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + COLUMN_DATE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_MARKET_ID + " INTEGER, "
        + COLUMN_PRICE + " REAL, "
        + COLUMN_SUBSCRIBED + " INTEGER);";
```

Method to check what columns do I have:

```
private Market cursorToMarket(Cursor cursor) {
    Market market = new Market();
    Log.d("X", "0: " +cursor.getColumnName(0));
    Log.d("X", "1: " +cursor.getColumnName(1));
    Log.d("X", "2: " +cursor.getColumnName(2));
    Log.d("X", "3: " +cursor.getColumnName(3));//Null - not even printed out
    Log.d("X", "4: " +cursor.getColumnName(4));//Null - not even printed out
    market.marketid = cursor.getInt(0);
    market.setDate(cursor.getString(2));
    market.price = cursor.getFloat(1);
    return market;
}
```

calling method on a cursor:

```
Cursor cursor = database.query(MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_MARKETS, allColumns, null, null, null, null, null);
Market mark = cursorToMarket(cursor);
```

No matter what SQLite creates only _id, price, and date column. Any ideas where I've made a mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added some columns recently? When you add new columns, you have to unistall your app and install again if you're using `onCreate()` method to create your database.

Also, make sure that `allColumns` parameter contains all columns.

Comment: Yes, I did uninstall, "clear data" of that app, even called "this.deleteDatabase("markets.db");"

Comment: What's in the `allColumns` parameter?

Comment: You are 100% correct "private String[] allColumns = { MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_ID, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_PRICE, MySQLiteHelper.COLUMN_DATE };"

So that was a problem. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

You should verify that `allColumns` actually includes all the columns in your database. That is the only reason I can think of that this would fail.